# how to check for multiple boolean function

Tags: java, android

I am trying to validate the registration number of a student before registration with firebase. I a created a method of type Boolean to validate the info but the issue I am having is that the method returns false even when the two conditions were true. I don't really know what I did wrong. thanks for your contributions

```
    private boolean success = false;
    
    
    private boolean authenticateRegistrationNumber(String registrationNumber){
            
            final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("Registration Numbers").child(registrationNumber);
            databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.exists()){
                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                        success = false;
                        showMessage("Error","This Registration Number does not exist in the database");
                    }else {
                        success = true;
                    }
                    if (success){
    
                        final DatabaseReference studentDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                                .child("Students").child(registrationNumber);
                        studentDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.exists()){
                                    success = false;
                                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                                    showMessage("Error","Student with this Registration Number has Already Registered");
                                }else {
                                    success = true;
                                }
                            }
    
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(StudentRegistrationActivity.this, "Database Error "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(StudentRegistrationActivity.this, "Database Error "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.d("Main","the success status is "+success);
            return success;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a return value when using listener because what happens is that you add the listener and then your code keeps on executing and immediately returns `success`. If you add a Log inside the listener methods you should see it.

```
 private boolean authenticateRegistrationNumber(String registrationNumber){
            
            final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("Registration Numbers").child(registrationNumber);
            databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
              // code runs later
            });
            Log.d("Main","the success status is "+success);
            return success;
        }
```

What you need is a callback which is given to your method and then called when the listener receives data and decides if the condition is `true` or `false`.

```
interface ResultListener {
    void onResult(boolean)
}


private void authenticateRegistrationNumber(
        String registrationNumber,
        resultListener: ResultListener
){
           final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("Registration Numbers").child(registrationNumber);
            databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.exists()){
                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                        success = false;
                        showMessage("Error","This Registration Number does not exist in the database");
                    }else {
                        success = true;
                    }

                    listener.onResult(success)                      
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    listener.onResult(false)
                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(StudentRegistrationActivity.this, "Database Error "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

You create the listener outside the method and handle any result in its callback. I would suggest that you also move the second part inside the listener callback to have a better separation

```
onResult(boolean success) {
    if(!success) return

    final DatabaseReference studentDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                                    .child("Students").child(registrationNumber);
                            studentDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.exists()){
                                        success = false;
                                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                                        showMessage("Error","Student with this Registration Number has Already Registered");
                                    }else {
                                        success = true;
                                    }
                                }
        
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(StudentRegistrationActivity.this, "Database Error "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
}
```

Also all your code which is working with the result of `authenticateRegistrationNumber()` must be placed inside the `Listener` method.

Comment: when I create the interface with the method onResult(boolean), they are telling me that the method need to have a return type, please how should I go about it @Daniel Knauf?

Comment: Ah yes sorry. Tried to do Java but am so used to Kotlin. The return type should be void. Usually you do not return anything from callbacks

Comment: The stuff is still requesting that I must have a return statement of type boolean when I implemented this your code @Daniel Knauf. Please any way out?

Comment: I needed a situation whereby I will only call the method if and only if the two conditions in the authentication were true

Comment: Sorry again for being careless. I forgot to change the return type from boolean to void : private void authenticateRegistrationNumber(...){} - I also updated my answer.